# Create a modal in ionic but present it in my own way

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

I would like to use Ionic *modalController* to create a modal from an external page, but rather than calling **modal.present()** I would like to attach the created modal component to the y value of a pan event.

The affect I'm going for is the user dragging the modal up from a drawer handle which is the footer.

Below is some stripped down code, this is a simplified version and I realise that it is incomplete, but it serves in demonstrating what I want to do for this question.

```
export class MyPage {

  myModal: any;

  constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef, public modalCtrl: ModalController) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let hammer = new window['Hammer'](this.elementRef.nativeElement);
    hammer.get('pan').set({ direction: window['Hammer'].DIRECTION_VERTICAL });

    hammer.on('panstart', (event) => {
      this.onPanstart(event);
    });

    hammer.on('pan', (event) => {
      this.onPan(event);
    });
  }

  onPanstart(event) {
    this.myModal = this.modalCtrl.create('MyModalPage');
  };

  onPan(event) {
    // This is where I am stuck...
    // Rather than calling modal present,
    // I want to allow the modal to be draggable.

    this.myModal.y = event.center.y;
  };
}
```

There is [this excellent tutorial by Josh Morony](https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-sliding-drawer-component-for-ionic-2/) that explores what I'm attempting to do but the crucial difference is that I need to use a modal page for my implementation and a ion-footer component as the drawer handle.

[image: An example of the UI I'm aiming for...]

I'm not sure how I can use the object returned from **ModalController.create()** or how I would apply css to position the modal window.
All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried `this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.playingNowModal, 'top', event.center.y+'px !important');` ... Didn't work.

Comment: Can you share a ui mockup of target user experience in this case?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko, I've edited the question to add example of my target UX.. it's essentially a pull up sliding modal drawer.. Like the _Playing Now_ tab in the mobile _Spotify_ app. You can swipe or pull up a tab that reveals a modal page.